# Adding datepicker event handler multiple times

Tags: jquery, event-handling, datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Using jQuery I'm trying to add the datepicker event handler to an input element.

```
    <div id="Box_tmpl" style="border:solid 1px #777; background:#ddd; display: none;">
        <a class="remove-box" href="#">remove</a>
        <div>
            <label for="PeriodStart">Period (start):</label>
            <input id="PeriodStart" class="start-end-date" name="period_start" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="PeriodEnd">Period (end):</label>
            <input id="PeriodEnd" class="start-end-date" name="period_end" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="add-box" href="#" style="margin: 6px 0 10px auto;">add</a>

    <div id="Boxes">
        <div style="border:solid 1px #777; background:#ddd;">
            <a class="remove-box" href="#">remove</a>
            <div>
                <label for="PeriodStart">Period (start):</label>
                <input id="PeriodStart" class="start-end-date" name="period_start" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="PeriodEnd">Period (end):</label>
                <input id="PeriodEnd" class="start-end-date" name="period_end" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('.start-end-date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });

            $('.remove-box').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });

            $('.add-box').click(function(){
                $('#Box_tmpl').clone().removeAttr('id').show().appendTo('#Boxes');
                $('.start-end-date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
                $('.remove-box').click(function(){
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Adding a new box works.
Adding the remove-box event handler within the new box works.
Adding the datepicker event handler withing the new box DOES NOT work. I don't understand why... 
Creating a new element using $().clone() does the new element inherit the old element's event handlers? If it does, may be my problem is adding the datepicker event handler multiple times to the same element... I'm running out of ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use

```
$().clone(true)
```

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

> withDataAndEventsA Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as well.

for your question in the comment: when initializing, the datepicker adds a class "hasDatepicker" to the input. you can not reinitialize an Input with that class,
So if you want NOT to clone the events, you have to `.removeClass('hasDatepicker')` from your cloned input, then initialize it.

the code in your fiddle has to be changed:

```
$('#Box_tmpl').clone().removeAttr('id').find('input.start-end-date').removeClass('hasDatepicker').end().show().appendTo('#Boxes');
$('.start-end-date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

note: `.end()` rewinds to the state it was until `find()`

Comment: Delegation is more useful than cloning. Check my answer :)

Comment: he asked about clone and the bound events. That was what I focused on. You are right by pointing out, that there are better ways to solve that problem.

Comment: Thanx StilgarBF! The param 'true' solves my problem. But what if I don't want to copy the event handlers? What if I want to add new event handlers? Especially the datepicker... The datepicker [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XVHqJ/) does not work... Any ideas why?

Comment: please do not add more questions in a comment. I edited my answer. - hope that helps.  please don't forget to vote up if that was helping.

Comment: Sorry... what would be the right way to add more questions? (again I'm asking in the comment ;-) ... editing my first question???

Comment: yes - edit / clearify your question. that will help others with the same problem if they find your question later. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1):

In order to bind the event to the dynamically created or cloned elements use .on()

```
$('#Boxes').on('click', '.remove-box', function(){
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/TSqbs/1)

Comment: Thanx Starx! When using the .on() method I don't have to do the extra $('.remove-box').click() within the $('.add-box').click(function(){}). But that still does not explain why the datepicker does not work... see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XVHqJ/)

Comment: @esviko, The binder do not function when cloned, pass a true parameter to `.clone()` method. Check a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/XVHqJ/1/)